# Update website when data in SQL Server changes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am stuck in a problem. There is an application that adds data to database, which is a closed source. 
I am creating its web interface. The functionality I want is, that, if a value of some Field in a column is greater than a value in another field in a column, SQL server should http post a message to my site.

Is it possible in Microsoft SQL?
and if yes, How?

Comment: A CLR Trigger might be useful for you. Unfortunately, that's all I know since I've never needed one yet. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/938d9dz2(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: is Transact-SQL a possible answer?

Comment: transact-sql is just the dialect of SQL that Sql Server uses.

Comment: what is the purpose of this http post that you want to happen? Are you keeping a separate database behind your website that you'll update?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if another software is doing the inserts, you could do it like this...

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ABCD] ON [dbo].[XXX] 
FOR INSERT
AS
    Declare @A -- from column 1 in INSERT
    Declare @B -- from column 2 in INSERT

    if (@A > @b)
        begin
              EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
              @recipients = @email,
              @body = @message,
              @subject = 'Latest record has column value A greater than column value B'
        end
    else 
        begin
        --do whatever
        end
```

Ps. `sp_send_dbmail` is a `stored procedure` that sends email or messages

Comment: No, thats the point, inserting data is not in my control. I dont do that, some other software does that

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi Could you add a trigger to a table? I suppose `sp_send_dbmail` can also be invoked from a trigger...

Comment: Yes, you are right. you can invoke sp_send_dbmail from a trigger. I just edited the code above as well